# write raw binary to file java

Tags: java, binary

Say I have a binary string ("0 and 1s") and I want to write this string to a binary file, how can this be done in java? I tried converting to ASCII values string, then create a ByteArrayInputStream from that but values over 127 do not display correctly. Can anyone help me with this? 
My binaryToAscii method:

```
public static String BinaryToAscii(String bin){
    int num_of_bytes = bin.length()/8;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int index = 0;
    String byte_code;
    Character char_code;
    for (int i =0; i<num_of_bytes;i++){
        index = i*8;
        byte_code = bin.substring(index,index+8);
        int charCode = Integer.parseInt(byte_code, 2);
        char_code = new Character((char)charCode);
        sb.append(char_code);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then I convert the returned string to a ByteArrayInputStream using

> InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(ascii.toString().getBytes());

Comment: Instead of thank you notes please show example of what you have as input and what you want as output. Also showing code you've tried would make positive impression...

Comment: your method should not return String, it should return a byte[]

Comment: got it working with the bitwise operators, thank you alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you first would transform the 0 / 1 string to a byte[].

then write out using

```
DataOutputStream.writeByte().

read in with
DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte() // to get 0 - 255
```

Comment: How would I convert the string to a byte[]? Is values that is over 127 going to cause problems?

Comment: [String : getBytes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29)

Comment: no not getBytes, you dont want to have a String to byte[] conversion. you want a 0/1 string to byte representarion conversion

Comment: instead od Stringbuilder add the int read in line Integer.parseInt to an int ( or byte) array.

Comment: What method do you use to convert an integer to byte[] and keep the binary representation?

Comment: int is "sam"e as byte if int is <= 127, just add each of the ints to a int[] array and write each int with dataOurpuzstream.writeByte()

Comment: Does writeByte() ignore the sign? And I would have 4 chars for each entry in this int array

Comment: yes, and one char is one int. the secret is the readUnsignedbyte() that decides ifvyou get 0-255 or -127,128

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22731/discussion-between-user1538814-and-alexwien)

Answer (score 1):

To convert string to binary use this:
You will first need to break the string into its individual letters then run them through this one at a time.

```
char letter = c;
  byte[] bytes = letter.getBytes();
  StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
  for (byte b : bytes)
  {
     int val = b;
     for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
     {
        binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
        val <<= 1;
     }
     binary.append(' ');
  }
  System.out.println(binary);
```

Comment: i'm not sure where to go with this